# FlatFileItemWriter write header only in case when data is present

Tags: spring-batch

have a task to write header to file only if some data exist, other words if reader return nothing file created by writer should be empty.

Unfortunately FlatFileItemWriter implementation, in version 3.0.7, has only private access fields and methods and nested class that store all info about writing process, so I cannot just take and overwrite `write()` method. I need to copy-paste almost all content of FlatFileItemWriter to add small piece of new functionality.

Any idea how to achieve  this more elegantly in Spring Batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally found a less-more elegant solution.

The solution is to use `LineAggregators`, and seems in the current implementation of `FlatFileItemWriter` this is only one approach that you can use safer when inheriting this class.

I use a separate line aggregator only for a header, but the solution can be extended to use multiple aggregators.

Also in my case header is just predefined string, thus I use `PassThroughLineAggregator` by default that just return my string to `FlatFileItemWriter`.

```java
public class FlatFileItemWriterWithHeaderOnData extends FlatFileItemWriter {

    private LineAggregator lineAggregator;
    private LineAggregator headerLineAggregator = new PassThroughLineAggregator();

    private boolean applyHeaderAggregator = true;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(headerLineAggregator, "A HeaderLineAggregator must be provided.");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLineAggregator(LineAggregator lineAggregator) {
        this.lineAggregator = lineAggregator;
        super.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
    }

    public void setHeaderLineAggregator(LineAggregator headerLineAggregator) {
        this.headerLineAggregator = headerLineAggregator;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List items) throws Exception {
        if(applyHeaderAggregator){
            LineAggregator initialLineAggregator = lineAggregator;
            super.setLineAggregator(headerLineAggregator);
            super.write(getHeaderItems());
            super.setLineAggregator(initialLineAggregator);
            applyHeaderAggregator = false;
        }

        super.write(items);
    }

    private List<String> getHeaderItems() throws ItemStreamException {
        // your actual implementation goes here
        return Arrays.asList("Id,Name,Details");
    }
}
```

PS. This solution assumed that if method `write()` called then some data exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your writer

`writer.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(true);`

If you have no data, there is no file.
In other case, you write your header and your items

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of a way as below.

1. BeforeStep() (or a Tasklet) if there is no Data at all, you set a flag such as "noData" is 'true'. Otherwise will be 'false'
2. And you have 2 writers, one with Header and another one without Header. In this case you can have a base Writer acts as a parent and then 2 writers inherits it. The only difference between them is one with Header and one doesn't have HeaderCallBack.
3. Base on the flag, you can switch to either 'Writer with Header' or 'Writer without Header'

Thanks,
Nghia

Comment: there are some problems as for first look:

1. beforeStep we have the only stepExecution as parameter, so we actually still don't know if there will be data or not

2. FlatFileItemWriters will create two files on call to `open()` method

Comment: What I'm saying is, BeforeStep you can query database or do your logic to find out if there will be data or not. FlatFileItemWriter will *not* create two files, it is a switch either or not both.

Comment: I have a lot of data when executing SP, I don't want to do this two times. Seems this is not my way, thanks anyway.

Comment: You won't need to call the same Store Proc again. You can build another SP which just tell we have Data or not. The new SP doesn't need to pull whole data. It just needs to return a flag.